# How can I detect if a user tries to upvote once again?

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I'm currently in the process of implementing an upvoting system ( no down voting system will be used in the app). I managed to create an upvote property to the Post model in my app. The default for that property is 0 as shown here:

**models.py**

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(unique= True)
    email = CharField(unique= True)
    password = CharField(max_length = 100)
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default = False)
    confirmed = BooleanField(default = False)
    confirmed_on = DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-joined_at',)

    def get_posts(self):
        return Post.select().where(Post.user == self)

    def get_stream(self):
        return Post.select().where(
            (Post.user == self)
        )

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, is_admin= False, confirmed = False, confirmed_on = None):
        try:
            with DATABASE.transaction():
                cls.create(
                username = username,
                email = email,
                password = generate_password_hash(password),
                is_admin = is_admin,
                confirmed = confirmed,
                confirmed_on = confirmed_on)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("User already exists")

class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model = User,
        related_name = 'posts'
    )
    name = TextField()
    content = TextField()
    upvotes = IntegerField(default=0)
    url = TextField()
    category = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)
```

I managed to increment the value by making the user follow a link:

**stream.html**

```
 <div class="voting_bar">
        <a href="/vote/{{post.id}}"><img src="/static/img/upvote.png"></a>
        <p>{{post.upvotes}}</p>
      </div>
```

This will activate a function with the associated route:

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/vote/<int:post_id>')
def upvote(post_id):
    posts = models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id)
    if posts.count() == 0:
        abort(404)
    post = models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id).get()
    query = models.Post.update(upvotes = (post.upvotes+1)).where(models.Post.id == post_id)
    query.execute()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

My question is, how can I detect if the user had already voted? I'm not sure what I should do to accomplish this. My plan was that if I identify if the user tried to upvote again, what I would do is simply decrement their previous vote.

Comment: Keep track of votes in the `User` model.

Comment: Aren't you storing the userid of the user who voted on the post? If you're just incrementing the upvote count in your Post without keeping a track of the users who upvoted it, then there's no way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: **EDIT** I think I understood what you meant earlier. Are you referring to storing the userid within the link and then passing that back to the function as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best approach here would be to create a separate table called **Votes** which will have two columns. One will store the id of the Post and the other will store the id of the User. Each entry or row inside the table would count as one vote. If a user tries to vote on a particular post, you would first query the **Votes** table if a row with that user id exists. If it doesn't exist, you add the vote. If it does exist however, then you simply remove the vote. To get the total vote count of a particular post, you would again query the **Votes** table and count the number of rows with the given post id. This would also make your application scalable if in case you would like to add a downvote functionality in the future.

Comment: This description is by far the most helpful. Thank you so much Bidhan. I appreciate your help greatly. I appreciate everyones posts. Thank you all.

Comment: I like the approach, but I feel that the this data (vote counts) should be bound to a post, architecturally.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Bidhan's answer, you could implement something like this:

```
class Upvote(Model):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User)
    post = ForeignKeyField(Post)

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('user', 'post'), True),  # Unique index on user+post
        )
```

You could add methods to post:

```
def add_vote(self, user):
    try:
        with DATABASE.atomic():
             Vote.create(user=user, post=self)
    except IntegrityError:
        return False # User already voted
    else:
        return True # Vote added

def num_votes(self):
    return Vote.select().where(Vote.post == self).count()
```

Also just a tip, but you might use `atomic` instead of `transaction`, since the former supports nesting.

Comment: Thank you so much coleifer! :D

Comment: Coleifer, what do you mean by nesting when using atomic?

Comment: Transactions (i.e. `BEGIN`/`COMMIT`) cannot be nested, but using `atomic()`, peewee will correctly mix transactions with savepoints to ensure the atomicity of nested operations.

Comment: Coleifer, I think for the class "upvote" in your example, it was suppose to be class Vote. If that's not the case what does the class **upvote** do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a (de-duped) list of users who upvoted, on that post itself.

Comment: Or use a probabilistic data structure if you don't want to pay that full cost

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store a variable on the profile of the user whom upvoted the comment that signified that they had upvoted the comment previously? 
Then check if the upvoter had upvoted previously and prevent the tally from increasing while still keeping the tally.

*edit*
Or you could create a list to track the people who had upvoted like so:

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model = User,
        related_name = 'posts'
    )
    name = TextField()
    content = TextField()
    upvotes = IntegerField(default=0)
    upvoters = []
    url = TextField()
    category = TextField()
```

Append the users who upvoted to `post.upvoters` and then check the list before upping the tally

Comment: Oh, I see your strategy there! So whenever a post is upvoted on, I must first check if the user is in the **upvoters** list. If they are in the list, I simply can decrement the upvote, which symbolizes that they canceled there vote. I think I'll try this out.

Comment: A `set` is more efficient than a list for this purpose. Also upvotes count is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You make an account for each User in the Django server and Authenticate them using Django's inbuilt authorization module.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/

[ To check for a different version change the 1.8 in the url to the version you want ]

Using this you can ensure that only 1 user makes an upvote by using a Flag. When the upvote is done, the flag is set.

Comment: What `flag`? Where will you set it?